# My discord bot is not pinging everyone. It is sending the @everyone message, but its not pinging anybody. (Discord.js V13)

Tags: discord.js

My discord bot is not mentioning anybody after sending **@everyone**. Like, it is sending the **@everyone** message. But it doesn't ping anybody. I have my bot's permissions with pinging everyone enabled. But it still doesn't work.

Here's the code:

```
const discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    info: {
        name: "announcement",
        description: "Announcement!",
    },
    name: "announcement",
    description: "Announcement!",
    async execute(Discord, client, interaction){

        await interaction.reply(`@everyone`);
    }
}
```

I expect the bot to ping everyone, and it doesn't. That's the issue.

Comment: Does your bot have permission to mention @everyone? I would also suggest trying `<@everyone>`.

Comment: That does not work. I've tried it.

Comment: What about fetching the role from the guild directly? `interaction.reply(await interaction.guild.roles.fetch("@everyone"));`

Comment: What's the client constructor like? The reason might be in that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `allowedMentions:{parse:["everyone"]}` as option when sending a reply or message. 
 For example: 
`interaction.reply({content:'@everyone',allowedMentions:{parse:["everyone"]}})`

Answer (score 0):

You can change your client constructor to be as follows:

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
      intents: 32767,
      allowedMentions: {parse: ["roles", "users"], repliedUser: true}//this enables @everyone mention (parse users)
});
```